# while read a b c echo creates ^M

Tags: bash, while-loop, echo

I have a strange behavier and cannot find anything for it.

I run a command like this:

```
cat file.csv |grep "\/text\/"| awk -F '[/,]' '{print $5 "\t" $8 "\t" $9}' | sed -e "s/'/ /g" | while IFS=$'\t' read aa bb cc ; do echo "$'aa','$bb','$cc');"; done > out.txt
```

Then in `out.txt` i have an `^M` after `$cc` output at the end of each line.

If i remove the `'` after `$cc` then its  ok.

If i write a character, no matter what, after `$cc` it writes that `^M` after `$cc`.

Can someone explain this?
Or how can i avoid this?

Comment: Was `file.csv` created on Windows? This usually happens when you open raw texts file from Windows on Unix or Linux.

Comment: No, created with scrapy on centos. same host as i run the command above. i could try a dos2unix on the csv file, before i run the cat - while
Update: dos2unix really "repaired" the csv file. even when it was created on linux. Thanks for that hint! Too many trees in my wood :)